# Soundcloud API: get tracks reposts, get playlist stats, track playback_count error

Tags: python, api, soundcloud

I'm using python library https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python to fetch stats of users: followers and followings number, stats of tracks (likes, plays, reposts, comments, downloads).

But I'm unable to find out reposts field in

> http://api.soundcloud.com/users/**USER_ID**/tracks?consumer_key=**MY_CLIENT_ID**
>   http://api.soundcloud.com/users/**USER_ID**/playlists?consumer_key=**MY_CLIENT_ID**

Is there a way to fetch reposts stats too?

I'm also unable to find `favoriting_count` in playlist fields... is there a way to get it with soundcloud API?

Also, `playback_count` of tracks is not equal to plays count showed in soundcloud page of users. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answers.

from soundcloud API reference

> https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

- reposts stats is not implemented
- playlists stats are not implemented

For `playback_count` error, I found that if you get `playback_count` directly from track `uri`, the count is updated.
So to get the last updated `playback_count` of tracks of a user you should do:

```
import soundcloud    
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID)
tracks = client.get('/users/'+USERNAME+'/tracks')
for track in tracks:
    uri = track.uri
    track_info = client.get(uri)
    plays = track_info.playback_count
```